# Symfony3 Entity properties reset to null when flush()

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have react app with symfony api. I send data from the react app to the symfony api. Here is the code in the Symfony api

```
/**
     * Creates a new user entity.
     *
     * @Route("/post", name="user_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"})
     */
    function newAction(Request $request ) {

        $body = $request->getContent();
        $body = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $body);
        $body = json_decode($body,true);
        $username = $body['username'];
        $user = new User();
        $user->setUsername($username);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return new Response(var_dump($user),200);
    }
```

if I comment this line

```
$em->flush();
```

this is what is returned by the `var_dump($user)` when the react app sends "John" as username.

```
object(AppBundle\Entity\User)#264 (2) {
  ["id":"AppBundle\Entity\User":private]=>
  NULL
  ["username":"AppBundle\Entity\User":private]=>
  string(4) "John"
}
```

However with `$em->flush()` there is an internal server error. Here is the error

> [2017-07-28 12:02:56] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException: "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?)' with params [null]:  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null" at C:\xampp\htdocs\simple-api\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 112 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\NotNullConstraintViolationException(code: 0): An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (username) VALUES (?)' with params [null]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null at C:\xampp\htdocs\simple-api\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractMySQLDriver.php:112, Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null at C:\xampp\htdocs\simple-api\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:93, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null at C:\xampp\htdocs\simple-api\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php:91)"} []

This means that my object has `username` set to `John`, however - when I flush it - the property is reset to `null`.

Here is my User entity

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $username;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
}
```

I have seen other questions like this before but they include foreign keys and relationships between tables. I don't have anything like this. I have Entity with one property. What could the reason be?

Comment: maybe a lifecycle callback on flush or an event?

Comment: There is no event or anything updated or anything. If there is then it is not intentional. How can I check if there are any?

Comment: well.. you can use annonations, xml, yml. check out there: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html